# How to distribute python application with all dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

I want to distribute a python application with all its dependencies. Target machine doesn't have an outside connection so I can't `pip install` anything 
and all packages must be included.

I'm using python 2.7 for my application and the target machine has a different python version. I would like to pack python 2.7 as part of my distribution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Send a docker container?

Comment: I thought about it. but i can't use install docker on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distribute on Windows you can use py2exe: http://www.py2exe.org/
or cross-platform http://www.pyinstaller.org/

That way you convert your whole application to a single executable file, which includes everything you need to run it.

Comment: i need it for linux,

if my application gets parameters (via argparse) 
will it work with pyinstaller?

Comment: Yes, since you still pass arguments to that file the same way you do to normal `.py` file.

Comment: Thanks grael,

I tried to use pyinstaller, indeed it was easy to use. but for some reason on the target machine i get the following error:
"glibc_2.14' not found"

the machine that i am running the pyinstall is RHEL 7.2 and my target machine is RHEL 6.4

Comment: Meaby this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found